# Display header in controller method

Tags: magento-1.9, template, controllers

Is there any way to display header and footer in controller method without using

```
$this->loadLayout();
$this->renderLayout();
```

these two lines in a controller method.

I have created one template file for controller method but that template data is not displaying in my controller method.

When I am printing

```
 Zend_Debug::dump($this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles());
```

in controller method then it is printing an empty array.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**For getting header& footer,you can try below code:

```
 $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html_header');->setTemplate('page/html/header.phtml')->toHtml();

 $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html_footer');->setTemplate('page/html/footer.phtml')->toHtml();
```

But,Without `$this->loadLayout();` you cannot get header and footer properly.

---

Better *idea to remove content area section from page* using `$this->getLayout()->getBlock('root')->unsetChild('content');`

**You can try also below:**

```
public function IndexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
      $this->getLayout()->getBlock('root')->unsetChild('content');
    $this->renderLayout();

    }
```

Also you can remove breadcrumbs   by add *`$this->getLayout()->getBlock('root')->unsetChild('breadcrumbs');`*

Comment: Sorry @Amit but it is not working.

Comment: nothing is working. I have added screenshot of controller method.

Comment: when I add $this->loadLayout(); $this->renderLayout(); these lines then (content displaying in image) is displayed.

Comment: Please check now...